Installing a "C" wire in an older 2 wire furnace
I currently have a 70s era standing pilot gas furnace and am trying to install a Nest (2020 version) thermostat.  I know I have to add the "C" wire to my setup, but I am thinking something is not wired correctly.
The current connections, which are working somehow, is the bottom wire of my 24V transformer, black wire (2 wire), is connected to my Honeywill Fan/Limit switch control center.  It then exits the limit switch and is connected to my TH terminal on my gas valve.
The other side of the wire is hooked up to my TR terminal on my gas valve and is then routed over to the red wire of my thermostat wire.  The white wire of my thermostat wire is then connected to the other terminal of the transformer.
I have taken pictures of the internals of the furnace along with the wiring diagram on the furnace panel.





I am getting heat and working as it should, but have not been able to connect a "C" wire to any point to get the common I need.  By looking at all the other responses to the various posts about this, I am thinking that my wiring, although working (as it was originally hooked up), is not correct.
The weird thing is, I get 27vAC at the TH  and TR terminals of the gas valve and white wire terminal on the transformer whether the furnace is "On" or not running.  However, when I hook up my "C" wire (blue wire) on 18/5 Tstat wire (ran brand new by me) on either the white wire connection or black wire connection, I get "No power" at the Tstat.  (Also note, there is no voltage between the TH and TR terminals on the gas valve at either condition!)
Not sure what I am missing, or is this thing some kind of one off freak of the HVAC world?  Technically it is wired according to the schematic, so not sure what is going on.

The colors on the old thermostat wire were swapped. How it should have been wired is:

Red (R) comes from the transformer and
White (W) goes to the gas valve and
C will come from the other terminal on the transformer.

Old school mechanical thermostats don't care about R and W being swapped; anything that uses the C wire does care about it.
To check that you should be able to see a voltage differential of 24V between W and R at the thermostat (when it's disconnected/not heating). There should also be 24V between R and C, and zero between W and C when not heating, but 24V when it is heating.
The Nest thermostat uses the voltage between R and C to power itself. If R and W are swapped then both R and C are effectively on the same side of the transformer. In that state it will refuse to operate because being miswired in some way means it might short out the transformer if it attempts to heat or cool.

Having said that it's about time for an upgrade; that ancient furnace is a lot less efficient than modern furnaces which condense the water vapor in the flue gasses.
It will pay you back by simple virtue of not burning as much gas for the same heat it pumps into your house.

Yes, I know I need to update the furnace.  That standing pilot system is super ancient and not good.  That is why I ran the 18/5 Tstat wire to replace the old 2 wire cable.  This way when I do upgrade, that tiny portion of the project is already in place.  The only question I have is where should the white wire connect to the gas valve.  The current setup has the red wire connected to the wire off the TR terminal.  I am thinking it needs to go to the valve itself?

I just double checked, wired the way it is, I do have 24v between R and W wires at the Tstat.  (When not running)

the Red wire should connect to the transformer terminal where the white wire was connected, the White wire should connect into the wirenut that connected through to the TR terminal on the valve. You can leave that wire from the TR to the wirenut in place because otherwise you would need to crimp a spade connected to the white wire.

That was it.  The two wires red and white were switched.  Thanks.  I had a feeling that is all it was, but I doubted myselt to try it out!  Appreciate your help.
